# REST api for my orders in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to get my orders information by using REST Api end point. Please suggest me any solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$userData = array("username" => "user", "password" => "password");
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/mage2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

echo $token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/mage2/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any default endpoint provided by magento for this?

Comment: this is default api which is provide by magento

Comment: above said program, get order details by using admin token, I need the same but using customer token instead of admin token.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/mage2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token to change http://127.0.0.1/mage2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token